# What is the correct way based on the consensus to write a volume measurement followed by its unit in liter?

Tags: siunitx

Which one is the correct one?

1. `100l` There is no space between number and unit. Unit is written in small letter.
2. `100L` There is no space between number and unit. Unit is written in big letter.
3. `100 l` There is a space and unit in small letter.
4. `100 L` There is a space and unit in big letter.

Comment: Then there is the question of *how much space* if there is space? For example, would a `\thinspace` make sense instead of a "full" space?

Comment: @morbusg. Indeed there is. A thin space emphasises the 'single entity' nature of the number-unit combination, and is the `siunitx` default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The capitalization depends in which part of the world you live!

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The pump in the US is pumping \SI{100}{\liter\per\second}, 
whereas in the rest of the world is pumping \SI{100}{\litre\per\second}.
\end{document}
```

As usual Joseph's `siunitx` package will typeset it correctly, except in South Africa, where the convention was and is to a large extend to use a cursive (l). Personally I never capitalize the `l`, after all you wouldn't capitalize *in*, so why would one capitalize litres and run the risk of the lb's complaining? In addition SI units only capitalize units that are derived from a person's name.  As for the space you unquestionably need it!

Comment: I'd agree entirely with Yiannis here: you definitely need a space, whereas the symbol is variable. (I always stick to cubic metres or derivatives thereof, which nicely sidesteps the issue.) @Yiannis. I've not come across the South African convention: can you point to a ref. for this?

Comment: @Joseph This was in the standard when I was living there! The standard is SABS M33a:1992 (I am not sure if there is an update), but here is a link  http://www.mecheng.sun.ac.za/Forstudents/docs/General/SIguide.pdf I also avoid using litres as much as I can!

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear this is really a TeX question.  But you can get an answer here http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_summary_en.pdf.  Either `l` or `L` is permitted. SI seems to like a space; others don't.

The `siunitx` package gives you various options, and is a must if you are concerned about consistency in your documents.

Comment: please don't downvote the question, as the answers to it hold everything I was looking for: what is the convention (capital letter? space? how spacy a space?) and the implementation in LaTeX. this is the place I look for LaTeX related problems and I found an answer right here, so it is in the right place, Isay. Anyways, I don't think this question is suddenly going to disappear after 6 years, but still :D it helped me, it could help others ;)

Comment: @thymaro Haha no chance of that. It takes 5 votes to close a question and I wouldn't have posted an answer if I thought the question should have been closed.